# Show all the routes at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 points, i.e A & B

I am drawing all those delivery points on Google Map which lies between point A and B.

Main goal to achieve here is to show all those multiple routes at the same time on Map, the zoom should be good enough to show all the routes on map.

Here is a working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Map</title>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;

var origin = { lat: 40.6159134, lng: -74.0234863 };
var destination = { lat: 40.9132885, lng: -73.8340076 };

var locations = [
  { loadingLat: 40.8499301, loadingLng: -73.8449108, deliveryLat: 40.887934, deliveryLng: -73.828483 },
  { loadingLat: 40.7702993, loadingLng: -73.8792667, deliveryLat: 40.8246079, deliveryLng: -73.8713595 },
  { loadingLat: 40.7246827, loadingLng: -73.9347472, deliveryLat: 40.7567285, deliveryLng: -73.9142167 }
];


function addMarker(lat, lng, type, map) {

  var coordinates = { lat: lat, lng: lng };
  //var icon = 'AA.png';
  var infoWindowContent = '<div><b>Pickup Point:</b> '+type+'</div>';

  if(type == 'delivery'){

    //icon = 'BB.png';
    infoWindowContent = '<div><b>Delivery Point:</b> '+type+'</div>';
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position: coordinates,
      map: map,
      animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: infoWindowContent
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  //infowindw.open(map, marker); 
};

function initialize(){

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),{

    //zoom: 14,
    center: { lat: origin.lat, lng: origin.lng }
  });

  function renderDirections(result) {

    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    directionsRenderer.setOptions({suppressMarkers: true}); 
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
  }

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  function requestDirections(loadingLat, loadingLng, deliveryLat, deliveryLng) {

    directionsService.route({

      origin: { lat: loadingLat, lng: loadingLng }, 
      destination: { lat: deliveryLat, lng: deliveryLng },
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    }, 
    function(result) {

      addMarker(loadingLat, loadingLng, 'pickup', map);
      addMarker(deliveryLat, deliveryLng, 'delivery', map);
      renderDirections(result);
    });
  }

  requestDirections(origin.lat, origin.lng, destination.lat, destination.lng);

  for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){

    requestDirections(locations[i].loadingLat, locations[i].loadingLng, locations[i].deliveryLat, locations[i].deliveryLng);
  }
}


</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="initialize();">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:1000px; height: 900px; margin:auto; background-color: #09F;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only issue here is that the map zoom is totally random, it wont show all the routes at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DirectionsRenderer` automatically zooms the map to fit the bounds.  That is what is causing the "random" zooming behavior you are seeing.  The directions service is asynchronous, the map is left zoomed to the last one rendered, which won't always be the same one.

If you are making multiple directions requests, and you want the end result to show all of them, zoom the map to the union of the routes' bounds.

```
function renderDirections(result) {
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsRenderer.setOptions({
    suppressMarkers: true, 
    preserveViewport: true  // <============================== prevent the "auto" zoom
  }); 
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
  // calculate the union of bounds
  if (bounds.isEmpty()) bounds=result.routes[0].bounds;
  else bounds.union(result.routes[0].bounds);
  map.fitBounds(bounds); // zoom the map to fit the union of the bounds
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/42pmgd5a/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #09F;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initialize"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var bounds;

  var origin = { lat: 40.6159134, lng: -74.0234863 };
  var destination = { lat: 40.9132885, lng: -73.8340076 };

  var locations = [
    {loadingLat: 40.8499301, loadingLng: -73.8449108, deliveryLat: 40.887934, deliveryLng: -73.828483 },
    {loadingLat: 40.7702993, loadingLng: -73.8792667, deliveryLat: 40.8246079, deliveryLng: -73.8713595 },
    {loadingLat: 40.7246827, loadingLng: -73.9347472, deliveryLat: 40.7567285, deliveryLng: -73.9142167 }
  ];

  function addMarker(lat, lng, type, map) {
    var coordinates = {
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    };
    var infoWindowContent = '<div><b>Pickup Point:</b> ' + type + '</div>';
    if (type == 'delivery') {
      infoWindowContent = '<div><b>Delivery Point:</b> ' + type + '</div>';
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coordinates,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: infoWindowContent
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  };

  function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: {
        lat: origin.lat,
        lng: origin.lng
      }
    });
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function renderDirections(result) {
      var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      directionsRenderer.setOptions({
        suppressMarkers: true,
        preserveViewport: true
      });
      directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
      if (bounds.isEmpty()) bounds = result.routes[0].bounds;
      else bounds.union(result.routes[0].bounds);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function requestDirections(loadingLat, loadingLng, deliveryLat, deliveryLng) {
      directionsService.route({
          origin: {
            lat: loadingLat,
            lng: loadingLng
          },
          destination: {
            lat: deliveryLat,
            lng: deliveryLng
          },
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        function(result) {
          addMarker(loadingLat, loadingLng, 'pickup', map);
          addMarker(deliveryLat, deliveryLng, 'delivery', map);
          renderDirections(result);
        });
    }
    requestDirections(origin.lat, origin.lng, destination.lat, destination.lng);
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      requestDirections(locations[i].loadingLat, locations[i].loadingLng, locations[i].deliveryLat, locations[i].deliveryLng);
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```